# How can I open a random jFrame within my project folder when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, button, random, netbeans

I'm a beginner to Java, and I'm trying to create a simple virtual library with a random book selection feature, which will occur at the click of a button named "Random".

So far in my project, I have a login form, register form, homepage and 3 books contained in their own respective jFrames. In the homepage jFrame, I would like to have a button that will randomly choose one of the 3 book jFrames and open it. However, it shouldn't be able to open any of the other jFrames (login and register). Is there a way that I can achieve this? I am using Netbeans IDE 12.2

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the book contents as text and use a JFrame that read this data and showed it as a book?

Comment: Yeah, but I've also included a few images in each book so I think it would be easier to just navigate to other jFrames instead.

Comment: By text I also meant formatted text, which can include images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself, I first used a random number generator and then paired it with a few if-statements to randomly open a page, its not the most elegant solution but it works:

```
private void randomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int random_int = (int)(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
            if(random_int == 1){
                dispose();
                new book1().setVisible(true);
            }
            else if(random_int == 2){
                    dispose();
                    new book2().setVisible(true);
                 }
            else if(random_int == 3){
                    dispose();
                    new book3().setVisible(true);
                 }
    }
```